# Need a counterexample: A product of a cycle with itself will in general be a cycle.

Tags: permutations

Need a counterexample: A product of a cycle with itself will in general be a cycle.

I was thinking something in S_4.

Comment: You should mention at least the word "permutation" somewhere in your question's title...

Answer (score 1):

In $\;S_4\;$:

$$(1234)^2=(13)(24)$$

Comment: Note: This suggests that any cycle with order divisible by two might work. A cycle $c$ of order $2n$ generates a cyclic group of order $2n$. $c^2$ generates a cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: Indeed so, @MarkBennet +1